# Insertar dinámicamente un botón ("X") en html

Tags: laravel

Después del success de un ajax, creo un HTML con los resultados de la consulta según el siguiente código:

```
 var html = "";
 html+= "<b>Resultado</b>";
 html+= "<b>Dato1</b><br>"+fuente['datotabla1']";
 html+= "<b>Dato2</b>br>"+fuente['totabla2'];
```

Lo que quiero hacer es crear un botón de salida del tipo X ,he probado el 
 siguiente código sin resultado.

```
  html+="<a button id='cerrar'   type='button' 
 class='close' data-dismiss='modal' 
 aria-hidden='true'>×</a> ";
```

Agradecería comentarios.

Answer (score 0):

Es mejor crear elementos con `document.createElement()` y insertarlos en el DOM con `"elemento (document.body)".appendChild()`. En ves de concatenar texto en la variable `html`.

Ejemplo. Acá creo una función que crea elementos y los inserta en el DOM. Por parámetros se le pasa el nombre de la etiqueta, el contenido, y el padre (en donde se va a insertar).

```
crearElemento('d', 'ejemplo', document.body)

function crearElemento(etiqueta, contenido, padre) {
    const $elemento = document.createElement(etiqueta)
    $elemento.textContent = contenido
    padre.appendChild($elemento)
}
```

Te aconsejaría que crees un contenedor principal para todos esos elementos. Así cuando se pulse la "X", con JavaScript remueves el contenedor principal en donde se sitúan los elementos. Para no tener que removeros uno por uno (tambien puedes usar `display: none` con CSS).

Te aconsejaría que cambies la etiqueta `<a>` por un `<span>`, ya que no lo estas usando como ancla (usando el "`href`").

Comment: Perdona la tardanza,en contestar, he estado intentando aplicar el programário que hacía con html mediante el DOM ,es correcto y el resultado es el mismo,pero  si intento aplicar con el DOM la siguiente línea html+= "<br><br><a href='javascript:void(0)' class='m-t-20 m-r-20 m-b-20 btn btn-info btn-rounded hidden-xs hidden-sm waves-effect waves-light edit-evento' data-id="+tarea['id']+">Editar el Evento</a>"; resulta que DOM no la entiende ,donde html dice class DOM reconoce className y donde dice html data-id,DOM no lo reconoce.espero haberme explicado.